# Error inviting user to Bluemix Organization

Tags: ibm-cloud, invite

When I am trying to add one of my colleagues to my public Bluemix account it is giving an error message "This user is currently using a Beta account and cannot be invited this time. Try again later". Seems like this is a change from previous behavior. Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Should be handled through bluemix support. Not a SO question.

Answer (score 2):

Please complete the "Invite User" process in the New Bluemix Console instead of the Classic Console by clicking on **Invite Team Members** and completing the prompts.

Link to New Console:

https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/#overview

Answer (score 1):

@arpan, please [open a Bluemix Support ticket](https://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport). Stack Overflow is for technical programming questions. Bluemix account questions can best be answered on the [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html?sort=newest&smartspace=bluemix) forum or by contacting support directly.